# Error while compiling fuse in hadoop

Tags: windows, hadoop, video-streaming, fuse

I am trying to stream video using hadoop and I came across the following link

http://internetmemory.org/en/index.php/synapse/using_hadoop_for_video_streaming/

From this I learnt fuse can be used to mount HDFS as local file system and using fuse library we can make file operations. Also to mount I have followed the below link

http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/BuildFuseDfs023

As per the link, I switched to `hadoop-home/hadoop-hdfsproject/hadoop-hdfs` and gave the command `mvn package -Pnative`. But it shows the following error for me

```
main:
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 18.969 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-01-05T14:03:43+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 32M/613M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.7:
run (make) on project hadoop-hdfs: An Ant BuildException has occured: Execute fa
iled: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "cmake" (in directory "D:\hadoopso
urces\hadoop-2.5.1-src\hadoop-hdfs-project\hadoop-hdfs\target\native"): CreatePr
ocess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
[ERROR] around Ant part ...<exec dir="D:\hadoopsources\hadoop-2.5.1-src\hadoop-h
dfs-project\hadoop-hdfs\target/native" executable="cmake" failonerror="true">...
 @ 5:133 in D:\hadoopsources\hadoop-2.5.1-src\hadoop-hdfs-project\hadoop-hdfs\ta
rget\antrun\build-main.xml
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e swit
ch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please rea
d the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionE
xception
```

Can any one tell me how to resolve this?